# Tokenizing text by 3 sentences using NLTK and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, tokenize

I have a dataframe in pandas - 1 column named 'text'. Texts has a different lenght, but I need to tokenize each text into 3 sentences and then replace original dataframe.

Can anyone help?

Comment: show us your sample code that you tried or want to achive

Comment: This is easily found googling, so many examples online. What have you tried and where are you stuck/

Comment: @rafaelc I tried sent_tokenize and tweettokenizer. There a lot of tokenizers in nltk, but I can't get what is better?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you need. The final DataFrame has one column with a list of 3 sentences per row:

```
text_df = pd.DataFrame(["hello world. hello america. hello europe. hello africa.",
                       "hello world. hello antartica. hello europe. hello asia.",
                       "hello world. hello africa. hello antartica. hello world."]
                       , columns = ['text'])

text_df['text'] = text_df['text'].map(lambda x: re.split(r' *[\.\?!][\'"\)\]]* *', x)[:3]) # get list of 3 sentences
```

Output

```
print(text_df.to_string())
                                           text
0    [hello world, hello america, hello europe]
1  [hello world, hello antartica, hello europe]
2  [hello world, hello africa, hello antartica]
```